# PHPSpreadsheet - How to get the number of PDF pages after export

Tags: pdf, mpdf, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPSpreadsheet to update an invoice template (XLS) and then generate a PDF File out of it.

My question is: is there a way to get the number of PDF pages generated (since a single sheet could be split in several PDF pages depending on the number of rows), or do I need to re-open the generated PDF file with a dedicated library and get the page numbers from here?

I could make an estimation based on the number of row in my sheet but a long text could be displayed in two lines so it's not really accurate.

Thank you.